# Do shields prevent Sonya from gaining Fury?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

[Sonya's skills](http://heroesofthestorm.gamepedia.com/Sonya#Skills) includes the "Fury" trait:

> Generate Fury by dealing and taking damage. Using Abilities gives Sonya increased Movement Speed.

This brings back memories of Discipline Priests not being allowed to shield Warriors in the early WoW days, and leads to my question: **do shields prevent Sonya from gaining Fury**?

The type of shields I'm talking about are ones from e.g. Rehgar's talent "Earth Shield" or Tassadar's "Plasma Shield" skill. I've assumed all those shields act the same, though I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short: **No, they don't. Sonya gains fury when shields are active.**

As the description says:

> Generate Fury by **dealing and *taking*** damage. Using Abilities gives
>   Sonya increased Movement Speed.

I tried to capture it in screenshots, here's the output:

[image]
[image]

Both health bar and fury bar go up as Sonya takes damage and heals herself at the same time.